# Datatables javascript is not firing in Chrome or firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-chrome, firefox, datatables

I have a table which gets recprds form the database. I have used Datatables javascript for Column visibility. The javascript works fine within internal browser of eclipse but when I try to run in Chróme or Firefox or IE. The javascript code is given below

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http:://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0-rc.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0-rc.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.0/css/dataTables.colVis.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.0/js/dataTables.colVis.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable( {
        searching:false,
        "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip'
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Could anyone tell where the mistake is and why it is not firing in browsers.

Comment: Besides: I think it would be a good idea, to put the _jquery_-link above the _datatables.net_-link

Comment: Try it again after prefixing **http://** before the URL of CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Why not use protocol relative paths?

Comment: @ThomasJunk I have rearranged as you told with HTTP..but it still it does not work in Chrome,FF or IE but works fine within internal browsers..DOnt know where mistake lies

Comment: What is the -exact_ error when you open up your F12-devtools, the _console_ should list all the errors - if any

Comment: @ThomasJunk The console in eclipse doesn't show any error and it works perfectly fine within internal browser of eclispe..Even in FF and chrome it works but only the javascript which should display a button  is not there  in FF and Chrome

Comment: How is the button generated? And where should it be? Considered putting the _datatables_ initpart out of the $(document).ready()-clause?

Comment: @ThomasJunk It is part of Datatables jquery

Comment: @Braj I have included http as you suggested bit still it does not work in Chrome, IE or FF. Also I have included the java script  what I have used in the code..

Answer (score 0):

Datatables depends on jquery, so you need to load jquery, before any datatables libs...

colvis is a datatables plugin, are you including the datatables base script in your file as well...
order should be...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../js/dataTables.colVis.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have edited and rearranged the order of loading Jquery but still it does work in Chrome or Firefox

Comment: I've updated my answer... I think you are just missing the base DT library

Comment: I have edited my question and I have included the javascripts which I have used but it works only within internal browser of eclipse but not in chrome,firefox or IE. Dont know where the mistake is

Answer (score 0):

I rectified my mistake. The number  elements inside  of  was not equal to number of  elemets within  and hence the jscript was not firing. I fixed the issue by matching the numbers of  and  elements. Thanks for all your suggestions.